# c++ high memory and cpu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, cpu

ok well i have a simple game that uses really high of memory and cpu.
cpu goes over 44% and memory goes over 5000.
here is my code

[Code](http://pastebin.com/jFeEanhK)

how to fix this?

---

EDIT
memory: 5000 bytes.
cpu: 44% on i5
the program get slower by the time it runs.

Comment: 1) Indent your code. 2) See the help on getting it to format when you post to Stack Overflow. 3) Narrow your code down to the problem section or pastebin it somewhere if absolutely need be, but don't dump a whole unformatted problem on SO. If you want us to help you, make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: lol@frames inside frames inside frames

Comment: This code kinda reminds me of the movie inception. One piece frame inside other...

Comment: "and memory goes over 5000" <- Can we have a unit here? 5000 bytes? (Wow!) 5000 KiB? (not so much) 5000 MiB? (Yikes!)

Comment: So, what's it doing when the CPU usage gets high?  And what kind of CPU are we talking about?  44% usage on a 486 is less troubling than on an i7.

Comment: i just put the code in <pre></pre> and so many frames created

Comment: Also, have you run a profiler on it to see where the CPU time is going?

Comment: 5000 bytes of memory - really - this is nothing.

Comment: but why does the program slow down. the memory doesn't stop at 5000 it keeps going.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tackle something like this is to comment-out big chunks of code until you stop seeing runaway CPU/memory, and then gradually uncomment those chunks until you identify the problem.

After a quick scan of the code, I do wonder why you are starting eleven timers to update your game objects. It would be better to have a single timer that updates everything at once and then does a single Invalidate call.

Answer (score 2):

That's too much code to examine thoroughly.

Some general tips though: Evaluate how much memory you expect it to use. Is memory use growing as it runs or does it stop growing at some point? If it continually grows you probably have a leak. There are packages out there that can help you track down where it's leaking, or make sure that you use RAII (for example `shared_ptr`) to manage your memory. If memory holds steady at a large number you may want to revisit your algorithm and see where the memory is being used. Are you allocating a lot of duplicate data?

As for CPU use, the only way to figure out where the time is going is to profile your application and see where the profiler says the CPU is being spent. Then you can approach that smaller section of code and determine how to improve it. The most likely improvements are finding polynomial (or worse) time algorithms and making them sub-polynomial time.

Comment: well the memory won't stop growing so as the cpu

Comment: @Ramiz: Just google for C++ profiler and pick the one that is most appropriate (i.e. will work on the setup you are testing on).

Comment: FWIW, I think applying a profiler to a program this small is overkill, unless you already have one set up and know how to use it. (But learning how to use a profiler is a good idea.)

Comment: In order to facilitate the good suggestion above, you should try to consolidate your code - stick the balls in an array/vector and get rid of ball1, ball2...

You'll have a much better start on locating your performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your high cpu load may come from your main loop.

I usually use something like

```
while(gameIsRunning) //Set this to false when the WM_QUIT message arrives
  {
  //handle all messages, if any
  while (PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd,  0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) 
    {
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
      {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
    }

  //addition per loop code
  //...

  Sleep(1);
  }
```

Additionally, you should abandon timers and look into [QueryPerformanceTimer and QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) for timing and measuring.